# java check if jar was launched from command line or explorer

Tags: java, user-interface, command-line, jar

Is there a way to check if the jar was launched from command line via 'java -jar test.jar' or via double click in explorer?
I want it to start in nogui mode if it was executed from the command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no way to determine how it was launched. You could pass a command line argument like

```
java -cp . my.package.Example -nogui
```

And then parse the argument in your `main()` method to control the "command line" or "gui" mode.

Comment: Thank you. So that's why I couldn't find anything about this.