# Check if the java program is being triggered from command prompt

Tags: java, command-line, cmd

Is there a way in Java to identify if the program is being triggered from the command prompt?

I know when a C# program is triggered from CMD, it sets `RUN_FROM_CMD` environment variable to `TRUE` and can be identified using the below line of code, but the same does not work in Java.

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RUN_FROM_CMD")
```

Please Suggest a way, if there is any.

Comment: I cannot find any information about `RUN_FROM_CMD` variable, where did you get that info?

Comment: I am currently using `RUN_FROM_CMD` variable for one of my C# test projects, to determine if the program is being triggered from CMD.

Comment: `System.getenv("RUN_FROM_CMD");` will do the same thing as your C# snippet. Good luck!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tested this out, it returns `null` in both the cases, when I run it from Eclipse and when I run it from CMD.

Comment: @AppuMistri I said it does the same thing as your C# snippet. Do you run your C# code in eclipse? Because if you did, it would be `null` there too. Likewise, when you run your C# code on the command line, what is setting that environment variable?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No, I run my C# projects on Visual Studio or Jenkins. Likewise, for Java projects, I use Eclipse or Jenkins. It could be `MSBuild` (Which is being used to build and run my C# code) that sets the environment variable, but I'm really not sure about that. However, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817842/6513289) workes for me.